# Error in value of default parameter [Bug in Visual C++ 2008?]

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, compiler-construction

I am facing following issue while trying to use template in my code

I have some C++ code which i call from C functions.

Problem is I am getting different values in the following code for statement 1 and 2.

```
Type id : unsigned int
statement 1 : 4
statement 2 : 1
```

C++ Code :

```
template <typename T>
void func(T* value, unsigned int len = sizeof(T)) {
     cout << "Type id : " << typeid(T).name() << endl;
     cout << "statement 1 " << sizeof(T) << endl;
     cout << "statement 2 " << len << endl;
}

template <typename T>
void func1(T data) {
    T val = data;
    func(&val);
}


void test(void *ptr, unsigned int len) {
   switch(len) {
      case 1:
          func1(*(static_cast<uint32_t *>(ptr))
          break;
   }
}
```

This happens only on windows. On Linux it works fine.

Comment: What values did you get, and what did you expect?

Comment: my mistake.. updated the values that i get

Comment: What compiler are you using? Looks like a bug.

Comment: On windows using Visual studio 2008 express edition

Comment: This is definitely worth submiting to MS, try this link http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio

Comment: What do you mean by "C Code"? You can't call a template function in C.

Comment: Its actually a C++ method only.

Comment: are you using `cstdlib` or something else ?

Comment: I've just tried this code (Visual C++ 2008 sp1), and did not get your output (but the correct one). I tried with different ways of calling func1().

Comment: I tried this with using the express edition. Has any one else tried this and got the correct output ?

Comment: I have tried this using the express edition 2010. And it's working fine, in both case output is 4.

P.S: using 'stdint.h' for 'uint32_t'.

Comment: I tried it in MSVC 2008 Team Edition and got 4 and 4 for both statements. BTW, are you sure that that is an exact code, that you ran ? In your function `test` there are two symbols missing `)` and `;` at the end of line where func1 is calling

Answer (score 1):

I get 4,4. You might need SP installed